# protecting downloaded videos from unauthorise access in android

Tags: android, video, encryption, zip, password-protection

i need to restrict the bulk of videos downloaded (around 20MB) from my app playable from outside my App. When User tries to play the videos outside my App it should not play. i searched for this and came across about encryption and Decryption using  Cipherinputstream and CipherOutputstream.i read that decryption will take time so the User has to wait a while before playing video. i don't want the User to wait for more time.
Also the user can share the same videos on Whatsapp .
Is there any other approach to do this ? Please suggest

Comment: if you could keep the vidio in your own package then it is not accessable to other app , try this approch

Comment: If you do streaming decryption, then you might be able to play the start of the video while the remainder of the video is still decrypting. I suppose it depends whether the decryption happens fast enough to stop the video catching up with the end of the decrypted content.

Comment: Thanks for your replies...i know about the internal storage but i had bulk of videos around 20 MB  that has to be stored . So internal storage will not be sufficient

Comment: Hi guys... i updated my query.Please help

Comment: Hi ..Please some one help

Comment: hi please someone help...

Comment: hi..can somebody tell me how to lock a folder with password ..so that i can restrict the videos. Currently i am hiding the videos by creating folder with "." and creating .nomedia ..but this will  not fulfill my requirment. i browsed on google and didn't find the solution . Most of them  said its not possible in android . How are the Folder lock, app lock apps are working if it is not possible to do in android. Please help

Comment: Please some one confirm whether it is possible or not? if yes, please suggest the way to do it.